# android list point to position

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 3 items in my listView, problem is that the pointToPosition() method is returning 1 for first item in the list and -1 for third item in the list. The rawx and rawy positions are correct as they match the dX and dY positions given by the device dev tools. I can not therefore work out how to get the correct cursor position for the list item especially the last position as code returns -1 rather than position 2. I can paste further code if required

```
 int pos = listView.pointToPosition((int) arg1.getRawX(), (int) arg1.getRawY());
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.buzz.ContactFragment"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"

        />
...
```

Fragment

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener, View.OnTouchListener {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        gdc = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
...
}

...

 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

        int pos = listView.pointToPosition((int) arg1.getRawX(), (int) arg1.getRawY());
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor)listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
...
}
...
```

Comment: Why dont you use onItemClickListener();

Comment: I want to support swipe, double tap and longpress , i am therefore using gesturedetector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved based on suggestions found on the web but sorry can not remember the url.

```
public int getTouchPosition(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    // Transient properties
    int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
    float mDownX;
    int mDownPosition=-1;
    View mDownView=null;

    //   Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
    int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
    mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
    int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
    int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
    View child;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
           child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
           child.getHitRect(rect);
           if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                  mDownView = child;
                  break;
           }
    }

    if (mDownView != null) {
           mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
           mDownPosition = mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);
    }

    return mDownPosition;

 }
```

Can use the position to get the cursor position used to populate the view

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor)mListView.getItemAtPosition(mDownPosition);
```